# Can't log in to my Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow, login, my-logins

I created another Stack Overflow account for another community that was not related to my main account, but I mistakenly added a GitHub login method with the mail from my main account. After that, my profiles merged, and I only have access to my account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/19666321/oleg-lysiak), and I can't log into this new one https://stackoverflow.com/users/21112628/rishala-itshnyk

Thanks

Comment: Who is this "Rishala Itshnyk"? IRL friend? Why using name of a different person? Anyway, everything you can do is explained in the faq.

Comment: It's not a name, it's a nickname. The account is not intended for professional, but for educational purposes, which I did not want to place on my main account.

Comment: Well it's totally different, so makes it hard to know it's the same person. Anyway if you can prove both are yours, you should be able to gain access by merging them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try to contact StackOverflow support, maybe they can help.